# Redo method using Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: vb.net

how might I redo this method with Activator.CreateInstance

```
    Public Overridable Function setCreditType() As CreditType 
    Select Case creditTypeId 
        Case Is = 0 
            Return New NewCredit(Me) 
        Case Is = 1 
            Return New ExecutiveProducer(Me) 
        Case Is = 2 
            Return New Producer(Me) 
        Case Else 
            Return New NullCredit(Me) 
    End Select 
End Function
```

Comment: More importantly, why would you?

Comment: I presently have a list of 105 classes and that may grow so someone sugested that it might be a good idea to find a way to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most literal response is something like this:

```
Dim t As Type = GetType(Foo) 'Get Foo from somewhere
Dim ctorArgs() New As Object { Me }
Return (CreditType)Activator.CreateInstance(t, ctorArgs)
```

Comment: Had some syntax issues which I have overcome but now I get the error "Constructor on type 'Type' not found." even though I have a constructor on the base type that takes the base type

Comment: It sounds like you are now trying to construct an instance of the System.Type object, not one of your actual CreditTypes. Can you post your code?